# Nested Case equivalent query in postgres to increase performance

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a nested case query with dummy structure added below.
I wanted to know can the same process can be written in different form so to increase performance as it contains more cases.

```
SELECT 
    COL_KEY,
    COL_TYPE,
      ( CASE WHEN COL_TYPE='A' 
        THEN (

            SELECT COL_EMP_NUMBER FROM TABLE_EMP WHERE COL_KEY = 
                CASE WHEN   
                (
                    select COUNT(COL_PRI_RELATION_KEY)
                    from TABLE_RELATION
                    where COL_RELATION_KEY = COL_KEY
                ) > 0 THEN
                (
                    select COL_PRI_RELATION_KEY
                    from TABLE_RELATION
                    where COL_RELATION_KEY = COL_KEY
                )
                ELSE
                    COL_KEY
                END
        )
            ELSE (SELECT COL_EMP_NUMBER FROM TABLE_EMP WHERE COL_KEY = COL_KEY)
       END) AS COL_EMP_NUMBER,
FROM TABLE_LED tld
AND tld.COL_KEY = '1234'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow such pseudocode. Could you perhaps share some example data and the result you'd like to get for it with such a query?

Comment: Have updated the query with little more description..

Comment: still, without the dummy data and schema,  and without describing-listing approximate record counts in each involved table.   its hard to grasp whats really going on. If you ask a question and want a good answer, its in your best interests to provide dummy schema, data so the helping people can run and actually try your query within minutes after reading your question. without  spending  hours on recreating and guessing where there are problems, where something can be improved. otherwise we can give you some suggestions and guesses only not a real answer.

Comment: You absolutely need to supply "sample data" and "expected result" if you really want an answer. By the way, the sql snippet you have shared with us is incomplete, has syntax errors (no "where" for example)

Comment: Also, your query is most likely wrong: there are 2 cases where you filter for `COL_KEY = COL_KEY`, which is essentially `COL_KEY IS NOT NULL` (and most likely will return more than 1 row). You need to qualify your columns there with the appropriate table names.